# If I select by a maximum number and group by a name, how do I also get the identifier?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

It was very difficult to find the words for the title, but hopefully the problem is easily described. I have a table:

```
+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| identifier | version_number | name                |
+------------+----------------+---------------------+
|          1 |              1 | propositional-logic |
|          2 |              2 | propositional-logic |
|          3 |              3 | propositional-logic |
|          4 |              1 | natural-numbers     |
|          5 |              4 | propositional-logic |
|          6 |              2 | natural-numbers     |
|          7 |              3 | natural-numbers     |
|          8 |              4 | natural-numbers     |
|          9 |              5 | propositional-logic |
+------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

I want to get the 'latest version' for each name, returning the name and the identifier. I have gotten this far with a query:

```
select max(version_number),name from `release` group by name;
```

This comes close, returning the right version numbers and names...

`+---------------------+---------------------+
| max(version_number) | name                |
+---------------------+---------------------+
|                   4 | natural-numbers     |
|                   5 | propositional-logic |
+---------------------+---------------------+`

...but I need the identifiers, too. If I try the query...

```
select max(version_number),name,identifier from `release` group by name;
```

...I get an error. I think I understand where I am going wrong, but cannot find away around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, if anyone more experienced than me can think of a more descriptive title, please go right ahead and change it!

Comment: Can you point me to a correct answer, thank you.

Comment: I've also flagged your comment as rude, which you know but other users won't. And I will ask the moderator to remove your downvote. We are not all experts and the MySQL manual is hard-going at the best of times. If you cannot manage to be civil, the best thing you can do is to simply ignore the question.

Comment: @BillKarwin, it would be better if you could provide a link to the duplicate question. Otherwise your intervention is also not very helpful, although you have at least managed not to be rude.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to be helpful. Marking a question as a duplicate does insert a link at the top of the question. Stack Overflow intentionally allows questions to be closed when they are duplicates of past questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: And I agree that Strawberry was being unhelpful. The comment above is no better than an abrupt "RTFM!" which should warrant moderator attention.

Comment: My apologies and thanks. My pathetic excuse is that I was unnerved by the first comment. I didn't see the link at the top of the question.

Comment: I also added the tag [tag:greatest-n-per-group] which should help you find other similar answers.

Comment: You're too kind. My thanks again.

Comment: And there's always the section in the online MySQL tutorial for "Examples of Common Queries" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: I think I get the idea, Bill. Sometimes, when it's late, and it's been a long day, I kid myself it's easier just to ask on SE.

Comment: @billkarwin agree with who/what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join on the ma version

```
select r.name,r.identifier,r.version_number 
from `release` r
inner join  ( 
select max(version_number) as maximum_version_number, name 
from `release`
group by name  
) t on  t.maximum_version_number = r.version_number  and t.name = r.name
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. I'd hoped to avoid joins but I'm beginning to understand that that is not possible.

Comment: Nearly there, but MySQL complains about ambiguous column names in the (I guess) outer `SELECT` statement, so I've altered your answer a little.